# DOM - preferred way to access a select's value?

Tags: dom

In several recent answers I see this code given as the way to retrieve the currently selected value of a `<select>` tag:

```
el.options[el.selectedIndex].value
```

Whereas the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLSelectElement) says that the `.value` property of an HTMLSelectElement is equivalent ("*The value of this form control, that is, of the first selected option.*")

```
el.value
```

Is there some reason (old broken browsers?) why the longer version seems to be preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my best knowledge, the `.value` way has **always** worked.

There is actually an extra problem with the first one - what happens when the user has not yet selected an option? Then the `.selectedIndex` is -1, which will make your script crash.

So go with `el.value`